# setting a datediff to meet multiple criterias

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to write the following condition to meet multiple criteria's as seen below:

=DATEDIF($E7,$E$5,"D")<=30 and >=14

So what I want is that if the number of days range between 30 - 14 then the conditional formatting would go to yellow but I can't seem to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is off.  Try:

```
=AND(DATEDIF($E7,$E$5,"D")<=30, DATEDIF($E7,$E$5,"D") >=14)
```

Also, since Excel stores dates as numbers of days since 1 jan 1900, DATEDIF with the "D" argument is not really needed.

```
=AND(($E$5-$E7) <=30, ($E$5-$E7) >=14)
```

should work just as well, unless there is an issue with times as part of the date stamp.

Comment: @Jaysorn Glad to help.  You may mark my response as the answer.